# Changing the Header height/size Winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, custom-controls

Is it possible to change the height or style of the header in `windows-form`.

[image]

I did look for the property where I can change the header but didn't found anything.

Is it possible with standard form or by creating own `custom-control`?

Comment: check out this link, its talking about changing color etc, may be you will find something to change height or width, though I am not sure http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/485fb4c5-8430-4cb5-8a4d-ccd7892e403b

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot change the Chrome with WinForms, unless you set the FormBorderStyle to None and implement your own header like a UserControl putting whatever you want there.

Then you will need to implement some basic functionality like moving the form, closing it, etc.